# How to get version of used dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm working on set of webparts that uses common library.
To testing deployment I need to add version info in generated html. Method that add version "watermark" to page is in common library.

So I have something like this (it is more complicated, because in common library is base class for webparts, but for this problem we can simplify it):

In control from mainAssembly.dll I'm calling OnInit method:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)  
{  
..  
    Library.AddWatermark(this);  
..  
}
```

and in common library I have:

```
public void AddWatermark(Control ctrl)  
{    
    string assemblyVersion = GetAssemblyVersion();  
    ctrl.Controls.Add(new HiddenField { Value = string.Format("Version: {0}",   assemblyVersion ) });  
}
```

So my question is: how to get version of assembly when we are in method from this assembly? (in AddWatermark)? And if it is possible to get version of caller assembly? (mainAssembly)

Comment: Try and use Assembly.GetCurrent() and Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
        Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

Answer (score 7):

Version of caller assembly:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
AssemblyName assemName = assem.GetName();
Console.WriteLine(assemName.Version.Major);
Console.WriteLine(assemName.Version.Minor);
```

To get version of current assembly replace first line of code with

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```